# Why cannot I pass an ifstream variable to a function as a parameter?

Tags: c++, ifstream

I can run the first section outside of a function, however when I try to run the code with and ifstream object in a function I get the following error:

> no match for `operator>>` (operand types are `std::ifstream` (aka `std::basic_ifstream<char>`} and `const int`)

**CONSTANTS AND HEADERS**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <fstream>

#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int COLS = 5; //Declaring constant number of cols

const int ROWS = 7; //Declaring constant number of rows

const string FILENAME = "foodDrive.txt";

//Function Prototypes
```

**The following works:**

```
int main()
{
    int food[ROWS][COLS] = {0}; //declaring 2D array that will hold values

   ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(FILENAME);

  for (int r = 0; r < ROWS; r++) //Outer loop for rows
  {
    for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++) //inner loop for columns
    {
      inFile >> food[r][c];  //Take input from file and put into food
    }
  }
  inFile.close();
```

**However this does not**

```
void readArray(const int ary[][COLS],int rows)
{

   ifstream inFile;

    inFile.open(FILENAME);

  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) //Outer loop for rows
  {
    for (int c = 0; c < COLS; c++) //inner loop for columns

    {
      inFile >> ary[r][c];  //Take input from file and put into food
    }
  }
  inFile.close();
}
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing objects with meaningful values rather than default-initializing them and immediately overwriting the default values. In this case that means changing `ifstream inFile; inFile.open(FILENAME);` to `ifstream inFile(FILENAME);`. And you don't need to call `inFile.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Comment: *"no match for 'operator>>' (operand types are 'std::ifstream"* -- this appears to be cut off. The operand types are 'std::ifstream' and what?

Comment: sorry, (operand types are 'std::ifstream' (aka 'std::basic_ifstream<char>'} and 'const int'

Comment: @G-wizz03 So much better. Now someone familiar with the error can immediately spot that streaming to a `const` is a no-go, then jump to your code and quickly see why the destination is `const`. More efficient all around.

Answer (score 2):

Remove `const` in function header, I guess it should help:

```
void readArray(int ary[][COLS], int rows) { ...
```